# How to access payload from REST 404 response in Camel cxfrs?

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel

I have a Camel route which accesses a REST service. Things work ok if the REST response is 200 ok. However, if the response is 404, the REST service returns some additional info in the payload, which I cannot find a way to access.

This is part of a debug log from running it:

```
[Camel (rraaCamelContext) thread #2 - seda://from_rraa] INFO org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor - Inbound Message
----------------------------
ID: 2
Response-Code: 404
Encoding: ISO-8859-1
Content-Type: application/json
Headers: {Accept=[application/json], breadcrumbId=[ID-Steves-MacBook-Pro-local-53701-1446241733043-1-7], content-type=[application/json], OriginalHeader=[{name=VerifyEmployeeRequest, version=1, scac=rraa, timeSent=null, uuid=abcd-1234}], pin=[1234], reason=[INIT], Server=[Jetty(9.2.11.v20150529)], transfer-encoding=[chunked], User-Agent=[Apache CXF 3.1.2]}
Payload: { "employeeID": "bad-name", "message": "id not found" }
```

My route is set up as:

```
<route id="rraaIss">
  <from uri="seda:from_rraa"/>
  <process ref="issPreprocessor"/>
  <unmarshal ref="IssRequest"/>
  <process ref="webServiceProcessor"/>
  <to uri="cxfrs:bean:webService"/>
  <onException>
    <exception>javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException</exception>
    <handled><constant>true</constant></handled>
    <to uri="bean:crewServiceNotFoundProcessor"/>
  </onException>
  <process ref="packageWebServiceReplyForIss"/>
  <to uri="seda:to_rraa"/>
</route>
```

My `crewServiceNotFoundProcessor` bean gets called when the response is 404 and it can see the exception, but how can I get the payload from the original HTTP response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this working now. The main issue was that I defined the REST operation as:

```
@GET
@Path(value="/authentication/{scac}/employees/{id}")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public String verifyEmployee(@PathParam("scac") String scac,
                             @PathParam("id") String id,
                             @QueryParam("pin") String pin,
                             @QueryParam("reason") String reason);
```

When I changed the return type from String to Response, the complete Response was now available, and the throwExceptionOnFailure=false option now worked also. So, this was a newbie error.